# Type hint pytz timezone

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, pytz

I have a function that returns a `pytz.timezone('...')` object. For example for the function below, what should be the type hint for the return?

```
def myfunc(tz_str: str) -> ????:
  return pytz.timezone(tz_str)
```

And in general, how should we type hint objects from installed modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced with such a problem after starting using `mypy`

.
To resolve this use `types-pytz` - this [repository](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/main/stubs/pytz) with [stubs](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/stubs.html) for pytz:

- `pip install types-pytz`

> ```
> import pytz
> from pytz.tzinfo import DstTzInfo
> ```

> ```
> def get_timezone() -> DstTzInfo:
>    return pytz.timezone('UTC')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have hard-coded the argument to `timezone`, you know that the result will be an instance of `pytz.UTC`.

```
def myfunc() -> pytz.UTC:
    return pytz.timezone('UTC')
```

If the argument isn't know until runtime, for example,

```
def myfunc(tz: str) -> ...:
    return pytz.timezone(tz)
```

the best you could do is use the same return type as is defined for `timezone` itself, which can be found in the [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stubs/pytz/pytz/__init__.pyi). (The stub file appears to define parts of the type in the stub itself, rather than using types defined in the actual library. I did not dig into the source code to see exactly what should be used or how; I leave that as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: I agree with the fixed one. I edited my question so I convey my concern more accurately.

Thanks for the link. I take a look and if I found the answer I would update here.

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
from typing import Type, Union
from pytz.tzinfo import DstTzInfo, StaticTzInfo


class _UTCclass:
        pass

TzInfo = Union[_UTCclass, StaticTzInfo, DstTzInfo]



def myfunc(tz_str: str) -> TzInfo:
  return pytz.timezone(tz_str)
```

A bit ugly, but does the job.

Comment: But this `_UTCclass` is different than the one in the [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stubs/pytz/pytz/__init__.pyi). May I import the same `_UTCclass` defined there and use it in the Union?

Comment: i think usually classes prefixed with `_` are not meant to be imported, and you can't easily import it._.
in my case it's a solution to please `mypy` warnings, but if you want to properly import it - perhaps make your own custom fork of typeshed repo where you can import `_UTCclass` and use it in your project.

Comment: I agree. But how the _UTCclass defined by me is going to have the same type as the one in the library? I think mypy should reject that the correct type is being passed, doesn't?

Comment: i think no, – as long as name matches `mypy` will be satisfied.